# Query for the average call length for all users for a day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

A person uses their cell phone multiple times per day, and the length of their calls vary. I am tracking the length of the calls in a table:

```
Calls [callID, memberID, startTime, duration]
```

I need to a query to return the average call length for users **per day**. Per day means, if a user used the phone 3 times, first time for 5 minutes, second for 10 minutes and the last time for 7 minutes, the calculation is: `5 + 10 + 7 / 3 = ...`

Note:

1. People don't use the phone everyday, so we have to get the latest day's average per person and use this to get the overall average call duration.
2. we don't want to count anyone twice in the average, so only 1 row per user will go into calculating the average daily call duration.

Some clarifications...

I need a overall per day average, based on the per-user per-day average, using the users latest days numbers (since we are only counting a given user ONCE in the query), so it will mean we will be using different days avg. since people might not use the phone each day or on the same day even.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your note. How does the overall average depend on the "latest date"? How would your desired result look for several different people?

Comment: well we don't want to count people twice in the same query, so only one average per user will go into the global average.

Comment: So you want an overall per-day average based on the per-user per-day average?

Comment: I want a overall per day average, based on the per-user per-day average, using the users latest days numbers (since we are only counting a given user ONCE in the query), so it will mean we will be using different days avg. since people might not use the phone each day

Comment: I have added a bit of SQL that selects the latest date per user only.

Comment: I posted a solution that gives the resulting "per-user per-day average" per your posted requirements.  Taking their time from most recent day, averaging that, then averaging the aggregate of users.

Comment: Have you just more or less copied my SQL into your answer and wrapped it in a "SELECT AVG"? LOL

Comment: What about a call that starts at 4 minutes to midnight and ends at 6 minutes past midnight?  How should that be accounted for?

Comment: What about weighting the average? Should a user who makes 50 calls of 10 minutes each combined with a user who makes a single call of 120 mins average at half way between the two? I doubt you'd want that

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the DATETIME to something you can make "per day" groups on, so this would produce "yy/mm/dd".

```
SELECT
  memberId,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, startTime, 102) Day,
  AVG(Duration) AvgDuration
FROM
  Calls
WHERE
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, startTime, 102) = 
  (
    SELECT 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(startTime), 102) 
    FROM 
      Calls i WHERE i.memberId = Calls.memberId
  )
GROUP BY
   memberId,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, startTime, 102)
```

Use `LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, startTime, 120), 10)` to produce "yyyy-mm-dd".

For these kind of queries it would be helpful to have a dedicated "day only" column to avoid the whole conversion business and as a side effect make the query more readable.

Comment: it is returning multiple rows per member, I need the latest one only (just 1, and the latest one)

Comment: Then you only need to group by the date field ( CONVERT(VARCHAR, startTime, 102) )

Comment: But then the "per member" average would go away as well.

Comment: There is a ayntax error in your query, as there is no table called member, AND it doesn't get the overall average as the user asked for.

Comment: Quote: "we have to get the latest day's average per person". I figured the poster is able to put a simple SELECT AVG around that. You are right, and there is no table called "member", good job. ;-)

Comment: tomalak, you might want to modify your entry to correct the script error.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will get you the desired end results.

```
SELECT AVG(rt.UserDuration) AS AveragePerDay
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c1.MemberId,
        AVG(c1.Duration) AS "UserDuration"
    FROM Calls c1
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, c1.StartTime, 102) =
        (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(c2.StartTime), 102)
            FROM Calls c2
            WHERE c2.MemberId = c1.MemberId)
    GROUP By MemberId
) AS rt
```

THis accomplishes it by first creating a table with 1 record for each member and the average duration of their calls for the most recent day.  Then it simply averages all of those values to get the end "average call duration.  If you want to see a specific user, you can run just the innser SELECT section to get the member list

Comment: running the inner query (inside the from) returns: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: I just tested an you can run everything from the "SELECT c1.MemberId" town to the "Group BY MemberId" statement.

Comment: I hop that got what you needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
select average(duration) from calls group by date(startTime);
```

Comment: date() is not a function on SQL Server.

Comment: The question was originally tagged mysql.